# how do I build up a global like integer array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I build up a global like integer array?

I tried variations of the following:

```
@interface
int *iArray; //this space will vary depending upon need in the implementation
```

---

```
@implementation
...
int iArrayInit[4] = {1,2,3,4};
iArray = iArrayInit;
```

-bottom line:  I need to keep index values in array that I can access easily, and use of [NSArray intValue] maybe to slow.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to be static you can declare an `NSMutableArray` as static in the implementation file and expose static methods to access it. When using an `NSArray` the values need to be of type `id` which `NSNumber` can do. Here is an example which currently is not thread safe.

```
//.h file
@interface Foo : NSObject
{   
}

+(NSArray*)iArray;
+(void)addiArrayValue:(NSNumber*)value;

@end

//.m file
@implementation Foo

static NSMutableArray *_iArray;

+(void)initialize
{
    if([Foo class] == self)
    {
        _iArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

+(NSArray*)iArray
{
    return [[_iArray copy] autorelease];
}

+(void)addiArrayValue:(NSNumber*)value
{
    [_iArray addObject:value];
}

@end

//Use
[Foo addiArrayValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
[Foo addiArrayValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]];
NSLog(@"%@", [Foo iArray]);
```